# jpa pagingandsortingrepository save is skipping auto generated value by one

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using SPRING DATA JPA PagingAndSortingRepository to perform CRUD operations against ORACLE Tables.   the example has an auto generated ID field.   When I perform myrepo.save(), the posted value gets saved ok, but I noticed that the Id field is incremented by two.   for example,

1. I do a save and the auto gen id ended up being 64, for example
2. I then do a second save and the ID value will have a value of 66
3. I then do a second save and the ID value will have a value of 68

and so forth.   I tried adding allocationSize as in

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
```

but this did not help.   I still see the id increasing by 2.

the save request return an object.  So when I debug the problem in postman, the returned object seems to have the the Id increment by 1, but what ends up in the DB table is the postman displayed value, plus 1.

Please advise if this strange behavior is seen before.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How many objects are you saving to the database. Looks like you are using the same sequence for more than one entity.

Comment: Hello kimy82;  I am saving one object at a time.   The ORACLE table has its own sequence created along with a Trigger for that particular table and that is mapped to this one entity.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to place the strategy in the Id. The default one if you do not set it is AUTO and AUTO will give responsibility to the database which is using a kind of global increment strategy.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
```

This is the javadoc:

> Open Declaration javax.persistence.GenerationType.TABLE
>
> Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for
>   the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.
>
> javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO
>
> Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate
>   strategy for the particular database. The AUTO generation strategy may
>   expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to create one.
>   A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such resources in
>   the event that it does not support schema generation or cannot create
>   the schema resource at runtime.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are facing is that the SequenceGenerator is global to the application. If you are using the same named `seq` in other entities you will increment them as well. There are other strategies that may be better suited to deal with this. If this is for an ID of an entity I would suggest using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` This [link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated) provides more on the different types of GeneratedValues.

Comment: I do agree that this is the problem when using sequence. However, you do not have to use a sequence if you don't want to.

Comment: Hello;  I replaced .SEQUENCE with .IDENTITY and made sure that I am using unique named seq name.   I still see the same issue.   The strangest part is that in POSTMAN I get status 200OK and id {
    "id": 117    but what ends up in the ORACLE table is 118.   This is strange

Comment: can you post more about your entities? And how you are using them?